# mount error(115): Operation now in progress. Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

Tags: permissions, mount, samba, fstab, cifs

I am following the steps listed here to try to get my WD Passport Wireless Pro 3TB HDD to work with Lubuntu 18.04: http://tutodir.com/how-to-mount-wd-my-passport-wireless-pro-on-ubuntu/

I run into the title error below:

```
owner@G700:~$ sudo mkdir /mnt/MyPassport
owner@G700:~$ sudo mount -t cifs -o guest //MyPassportIP/MyPassport /mnt/MyPassport
mount error: could not resolve address for MyPassportIP: Unknown error

owner@G700:~$ sudo mount -t cifs -o guest //192.168.60.1/MyPassport /mnt/MyPassport
mount error(115): Operation now in progress
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

owner@G700:~$ sudo mount -t cifs -o guest //192.168.60.1/MyPassport /mnt/MyPassport
mount error(115): Operation now in progress
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

owner@G700:~$ sudo nano /etc/fstab
owner@G700:~$ sudo mount -a
mount error(115): Operation now in progress
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I believe this is the page being refered to, but I don't know what I should be looking for. Anyone know how to resolve this? https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs

Comment: Is your system IP address in the `192.168.60.xxx` range of IP addresses?  If so, you can normally go to your router and check the leases of the IP addresses and see what IP address your Passport drive has received.  If your system is not in `192.168.60.xxx` IP address range, check your manual for your Passport drive in making it work with your wireless network.  Most home networks default to `192.168.0.xxx` network and `192.168.60.xxx` is not in the same network so it would not be seen.

Comment: @Terrance Thanks, I don't believe it is and will review the manual. I think you are saying to move the IP address range or specify a new range to be whitelisted? I have gone into my router settings and seen this (last numbers replaced with X): `WAN IP Address: 100.XXX.XXX.X. DNS Server: 203.XXX.XXX.X, 203.xxx.xxx.X. LAN Gateway: 192.168.1.X`

Comment: You would need to set up your 3TB drive to be in the same range as your home network.  If you see http://www.subnet-calculator.com/ you can put in your IP address of your computer or router and it will show you what the valid IP address range is for your network.  Also, pay attention to the subnet / netmask as that is what determines your range.

Comment: Ok, I entered `100.xxx.xxx.X`. I see the range is `100.xxx.xxx.1 - 100.xxx.xxx.254`. I chose a number at random in that range. I immediately got a lost connection type of error in another non-linux computer in the admin area (for the drive's wifi). Fortunately going back to `http://192.168.60.1` still worked for accessing the drive's admin. Is there a better way to find a good IP to assign the device? How should it be tested to ensure it's valid?

Comment: You can use many number of thing to determine what you can use.  But for now, this might be your easiest.  First run from a terminal window `ip addr | awk '/inet/ {print $2}' | grep -v 127` so that it shows you what the IP address is that your computer is getting.  You should see a number maybe like `192.168.1.30/24` or something like that.  Then install `nmap` by `sudo apt install nmap`.  Then run `nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24` or what matches your network.  The first 3 number sets between the periods have to match your subnet then the last digit make 0.  The output will show you the IPs in use.

Comment: Ok, I now see this: `Nmap scan report for _gateway (192.168.1.1)
Host is up (0.19s latency).` (also for .33 and .37). But didn't you say to change my hard drive's ip to something in the `100.xxx.xxx.X` range as that matches the first 3 of my router's ip? I did this and it failed in the way mentioned previously.

Comment: Not the router external IP, but the internal which is 192.168.1.1.  Your IP starting with the 100.x.x.x is called your public IP and that's the external or the way to get to your network from the outside world.  Honesty,I would erase your comments here showing that IP address so others do try malicious things on your network by hacking in.

Comment: Your hard drive needs to be something in the 192.168.1.x network to be in the same as your computer.

Comment: I have alerted a moderator to edit out the external ip info. Now I have attempted to change my hard drive's ip in it's advanced settings. I changed it to `192.168.1.168`. Immediately the connection was lost. I went to http:// 192.168.1.168. The page was broken. I went to http:// 192.168.60.1 and the hard drive admin was still there, showing the old ip `192.168.60.1` under advanced. This is harder than I thought, any idea what the issue is now?

Comment: According to the manual http://products.wdc.com/library/UM/ENG/4779-706000.pdf it comes defaulted to DHCP.  So, when the drive is properly connected to your Wifi network it should have obtained an IP address automatically.  Once it was connected you should have been able to see what IP it got.  However, if you want to assign it statically, that would work fine too, but make sure that you are assigning it to an IP address that is outside the range of your home wifi network.  I don't have one of these drives so I can't duplicate what you are seeing.

Comment: What I mean by outside the range is that a lot of home networks default to 192.168.1.x for the network but the starting IP is 192.168.1.100 with the router IP being 192.168.1.1.  Which would mean that you could statically assign it from 192.168.1.2 - 192.168.1.99 and not conflict with IPs that could be assigned from the router.  You would need to access your router settings to see what the range is.

Answer (score 0):

Three issues with that tutorial:

1. the default share is not **MyPassport** but **Storage**
2. the server needs to be forced to SMB2 protocol only, due to the notorious vulnerabilities of SMB1, using ssh access and changing the relevant smb-global.conf
3. mounting then requires -o guest,vers=2.0